# How to concat strings using **kwargs using function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input will be like :

```
def concat_kwargs(**kwargs):
    pass

kwargs = {"arg1" : "Welcome", "arg2" : "To", "arg3" : "Python"}
concat_kwargs(**kwargs)
```

output should be like :

```
Welcome to python
```

Comment: What should the ordering be? Should it just be based off the argument number? Also, you're not properly assigning kwargs.

Comment: @Aplet123 i don't know all things in python now only started python .If you didn't even understand a beginners mindset means how can you be a pro.? just try to explain wrong things i did  instead of that just stop behaving like you know every thing bro .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def concat_kwargs(**kwargs):
    return ' '.join(kwargs.values())

kwargs = {"arg1" : "Welcome", "arg2" : "To", "arg3" : "Python"}
string = concat_kwargs(**kwargs)
print(string)
```

Keep in mind that dictionaries are unordered before  Python 3.6.

Comment: You rely on `values` maintaining an order in order to concatenate strings in the correct order, but python 3.5 and before do not have orderings for dictionary keys. In addition, if someone enters `{"arg2": "To", "arg1": "Welcome"}` or something of the like then your code will output the wrong string. Just because your function matches the output for one input in one case doesn't mean it's what the author intended or it'll work in all cases.

Comment: I am aware that I rely on them maintaining order, so does the question. He wants to concatenate values of the keyword arguments and that is precisely what the function does. How do you suggest I maintain order when by definition dictionaries are unordered and the question uses a dictionary.

Comment: @Aplet123 Your objection seems to be that the person who asked the question wants the wrong thing.

Comment: @daktoad omg ! i  did the same thing in  8 lines of code but u did in 5 line thanks bro.